# Display Oracle Reports in an ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, report

I have a web application written in C#/ASP.Net and the backend DB is Oracle.  There are already Oracle Reports written for this, I am just wondering how I go about hooking them up within the code?  What is the syntax for this, and how to pass parameters etc?

Everywhere I see seems to be using either Crystal or SQL Reporting Services instead..  Is there a reason no one seems to be using Oracle Reports in an ASP.Net web app?

Thanks in advance
Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a few applications that queried an Oracle Report Server.  I used a webservice call (but if I remember correctly it was more of an httprequest) to the Oracle Report Server.

Here's the documentation that I followed [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10464_05/bi.904/b13673/pbr_webservice.htm)

I actually prefer SSRS (sql server reporting services) because it's much easier to integrate into an asp.net application and seems to have more exporting formats (such as ms word).

Using Oracle Reports is perfectly fine.  Especially if you already have the infrastructure in place.

Comment: Yeah I went with a httprequest that followed a format like:  http://server_name/reports/rwservlet?config=ur_config_key&report=Your_Report_name&Your_parameter_name=parameter_value