# .NET web portal & SSRS on Linux

Tags: .net, sql-server, linux, reporting-services, mono

We got a requirement to develop an application using .NET - ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC, SSRS or any reporting tool, and Oracle or SQL Server; but these need to be deployed on a Linux environment.

The application will be a mid-size Internet-based portal, and we have to develop it from scratch. The client prefers to deploy on Linux as they already have a Linux box they would like to use.

- Q1) I have learned that we can develop an application in .NET and deploy it on Linux using [Grasshopper](http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=130).
- Q2) I am not sure if we can install SQL Server in Linux?
- Q3) I am not sure if we can install SSRS in Linux?
- Q4) I did google but didn't find anything for Q2 & Q3.  An alternate for Q2 we can go with is Oracle, but for Q3 what is an alternate option?

What are options here other then developing the application in Java :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than running a Windows VM on said Linux box, no, it is not possible to run the full stack you have listed on Linux.  See [a related JavaRanch discussion](http://www.coderanch.com/t/419733/Linux-UNIX/SSRS-Net-IIS-Linux).

Question by question:

- Q1) I have not used [Grasshopper](http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=130).  It looks like a reasonable option to consider, but I am leery of it essentially cross-compiling Mono to Java bytecode.  On the other hand, developing in VS would be nice if it works well.  Alternatively consider [targeting Mono directly](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/29f8e4c8-68ac-4b94-8002-10c0980d93a9/running-net-applicationwritten-in-c-on-linux-machine?forum=netfxtoolsdev).
- Q2) No, you cannot run SQL Server on Linux: Oracle is one RDBMS alternative, but there are others of course.
- Q3) No, you cannot run SSRS on Linux: [Oracle Reports](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/reports/overview/index.html) looks like an alternative reporting platform that would make sense if you go with Oracle for Q2.  Another SO post speaks to [displaying Oracle Reports' reports in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1161952/1810429).

*Having said this*, the customer having a Linux box they would like to use for a "mid-size Internet-based portal" yet to be developed...smells.  Any mid-sized Internet anything will typically use distinct web and database servers - and even another distinct server where a reporting platform is involved.  That does not even speak to *redundancy and fault-tolerance* - i.e. scaling each logical server layer horizontally.  Basically, planning around a single box - *Linux or Windows* - does not sound like a recipe for success.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. so can I integrate oracle reports with asp.net ?

Comment: @user2463514: I edited my answer to cite a SO post that speaks to displaying Oracle Reports' reports in ASP.NET.

Comment: The much better alternative would be to use PostGreSQL and Birt as a reporting solution. And yes, target mono directly. Use C#, don't use Visual Basic .NET. That way, you can run your stack on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct.  Microsoft now has a SQL Server for LINUX version that is available. [SQL Server on Linux](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-vnext-including-Linux)

Comment: @Brian H: SQL-Server on Linux does not include SSRS. SQL-Server on Linux is just the engine, BI will be ported "later". So no, this answer is still correct. Also mono and Grasshopper won't help, because ReportViewer uses WinAPI calls (dll-pinvokes). And it doesn't work on Wine either.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone being directed to this question and answer would be getting an answer that is no longer correct for what is selected.

You could use [.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/) and there is a version of [SQL Server on Linux](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-vnext-including-Linux) that is now available from Microsoft that would resolve these questions.  As for the BI components of SQL Server I have not seen a mention of them so far, but any corrections to my post from Stackoverflow users out there would be appreciated.

Comment: SQL-Server on Linux does not include SSRS. SQL-Server on Linux is just the engine, BI will be ported "later". And ReportViewer doesn't work on .NET Core (ReportViewer is not .NET Core, it's ordinary Windows-Only .NET, and it uses WinAPI dll-pinvokes, so it won't work with mono or grasshopper either).